# Drupal 7 Is the a way to programmatically know the Fields in a Content Type?

Tags: entities, nodes

In Drupal 7, i need to `Programmatically` create the nodes, by using:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = "movie";
```

After, just this codes above, and lets assume i don't know what are the fields for it.

- How can i get to know the `fields` and that field's `structure` for this Content Type?
- (or) Can i echo out the `fields` inside a Content Type and its `relations` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`field_info_instances();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) will get you a list of all field types on a specific entity/bundle.

For example:

```
$fields = field_info_instances('node', 'movie');
print_r($fields);
```

Will give you a list of all available fields on the node type of movie.