# How to programmatically display the fields available to a content type

Tags: entities, 8

I'm attempting to display a dropdown box of available fields based on a supplied content type. I'd like to retrieve these fields programmatically.

I'm able to get a list of available fields based on a node like so

```
$fields = array_keys($thisnode->getFields());
```

But I want to be able to get the fields based on a content type not based on a specific node.

I did see that it could be accomplished in Drupal 7 like so

```
$fields = field_info_instances('node', 'content-type');
```

based on an answer here [Drupal 7 Is the a way to programmatically know the Fields in a Content Type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46368/drupal-7-is-the-a-way-to-programmatically-know-the-fields-in-a-content-type)

However it seems like field_info_instances is not available in Drupal 8. I attempted using it and it said that the method is unavailable. Is there a method similar to field_info_instances in Drupal 8 that I can use to retrieve the fields of a specified content type?